# Looping through a 2D array of text boxes

Tags: vba, excel, loops, textbox

I have a user form having a 100 text boxes. They are arranged 10 x 10 arrays. The text boxes have names

```
C1_A1  to C1_A10 (first row)
C2_A1  to C2_A10 (second row)
..... 
C10_A1  to C10_A10 (tenth row)
```

How can I loop through the textboxes row by row. The code for the `textbox_change()` is given below. I successfully implemented this for a form containing 10 boxes. But now I have to scale to a form having 100 boxes and it is no longer practical.

```
Private Sub C1_A1_Change()
    Dim wt As Double 
    C1_A1.SetFocus
    If IsNumeric(C1_A1.Value) Then
        wt = CDbl(C1_A1.Value)
        If wt >= 0 And wt <= 1 Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            MsgBox "Enter a number between 0 and 1"
            C1_A1.Value = vbNullString
        End If 
    Else
        wt = 0 
    End If
End Sub


'an action button to read all values 
Private Sub ReadDataTT1_Click()
    Me.C1_A1.Value = Range("Wt!E9").Value
    ............
    Me.C10_A10.Value = Range("Wt!N18").Value
End Sub 


'an action button to save all values  
Private Sub SaveDataTT1_Click()      
    If C1A1.Value <> "" Then
        Range("Wt!E9").Value = C1_A1.Value
        ............  
        Range("Wt!N18").Value = C10_A10.Value
    End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: have the sheet check each row of ten boxes and then the macro check each row is complete...

Comment: Use a loop for those in front of "_" (say *RowLabel*), and inside, a loop for those after (say *ColLabel*). Then use `Me.Controls(RowLabel & "_" & ColLabel)` to access them.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use only one single event handler (`TextBox_Change` Event) for all text boxes you can use a class module.

1. Add a class module called `clsTextBox` with the following content:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public WithEvents pTbx As MSForms.TextBox

   Private Sub pTbx_Change()
       Dim wt As Double

       If IsNumeric(pTbx.Value) Then
           wt = CDbl(pTbx.Value)
           If wt >= 0 And wt <= 1 Then
               'do nothing
           Else
               MsgBox "Enter a number between 0 and 1"
               pTbx.Value = vbNullString
           End If
       Else
           wt = 0
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

   Note that this is the code you used in your `TextBox_Change` event which we want to apply to all text boxes.
2. Add the following to your user form to apply the class to your text boxes

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private mArrClsTbx(1 To 9) As clsTextBox   'change 9 to number of textboxes

   Const TbxRows As Long = 3   'change 3 to number of text box rows
   Const TbxCols As Long = 3   'change 3 to number of text box columns

   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
       Dim i As Long

       Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
       For iRow = 1 To TbxRows
           For iCol = 1 To TbxCols
               i = i + 1
               Set mArrClsTbx(i) = New clsTextBox
               Set mArrClsTbx(i).pTbx = Controls("C" & iRow & "_A" & iCol)
           Next iCol
       Next iRow
   End Sub
   ```
3. To read/save the values you can use a loop similar to the one above writing/reading cells instead of the two `Set` lines.

   ```
   Public Sub WriteDataToWorksheet()
       Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
       For iRow = 1 To TbxRows
           For iCol = 1 To TbxCols
               Worksheets("Wt").Range("E9").Offset(iRow - 1, iCol - 1).Value = Controls("C" & iRow & "_A" & iCol).Value
           Next iCol
       Next iRow
   End Sub

   Public Sub ReadDataFromWorksheet()
       Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
       For iRow = 1 To TbxRows
           For iCol = 1 To TbxCols
               Controls("C" & iRow & "_A" & iCol).Value = Worksheets("Wt").Range("E9").Offset(iRow - 1, iCol - 1).Value
           Next iCol
       Next iRow
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will get back after I try the code.

Comment: The code works beautifully. For ReadDataFromWorksheet() and WriteDataToWorksheet() I had used a slightly different method, but this is more compact and elegant. Thanks again for your valuable time